# How to access classess in main class within same package

Tags: java, class, package

I got one problem while accessing classes in main class within a same package....
it shows error like "bad class name\name.class
......

```
public class Showall
{
  void print()
  {
    System.out.println("We Will show all the details");
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Showall sa=new Showall();
    sa.print();
    Name n=new Name();
    n.showname();
  }
}
```

.............................
here Name is class which is placed in same package.
..................................

```
class Name
{
  void showname()
  {
    System.out.println("Satwinder");
  }
}
```

Comment: @saugok error is..."cant access name bad file .\Name.class

Answer (score 2):

Class names can only contains IDs (basically a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _) and `.`

Edit your question to show the code how you try to access the class.